# python - Convert pandas dataframe to json or dict and then back to df with non-unique columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, to-json

I need to send a dataframe from a backend to a frontend and so first need to convert it either to an object that is JSON serialisable or directly to JSON. The problem being that I have some dataframes that don't have unique cols. I've looked into the `orient` parameter, `to_json()`, `to_dict()` and `from_dict()` methods but still can't get it to work...

**The goal is to be able to convert the df to something json serializable and then back to its initial self.**

I'm also having a hard time copy-pasting it using pd.read_clipboard so I've included a sample df causing problems as an image (sorry!).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to make it work.

Here is a simple reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# create simple df with two identical named columns
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4]], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col1', 'col2'])

# orient='split' conservers order
jsonized_df = df.to_json(orient='split')

# suppose the df is part of a bigger data structure being sent to another app
random_dict = {'foo': 'bar'}
all_data = [random_dict, jsonized_df]
data_to_frontend = json.dumps(jsonized_df)

# then from the other app
all_data = json.loads(data_to_frontend)
final_df = pd.read_json(all_data[1], orient='split') #important to remember to include the orient parameter when reading the json df as well!
```

The final_df will be identical to the initial_df with order preserved!

Comment: Does this really work? I have `pandas==0.25.1` and get `Unmatched ''"' when when decoding 'string'`

Comment: @shadi you're right it seems to no longer work. It used to work with pandas 0.22.0